# How to modify time style in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am using time feature via MYSQL data-type which is displaying time in 00:00:00 format.

currently displaying:

post name

00:00:00

i want to display like this:

**post name**

*2 sec*

post name

2 hrs

post name

13 hrs

my code

```
<?php
$time = $row ['time_min'];

?>
<p><span><?php echo $time ?></span></p>
```

how can i do this? i have googled alot but i am not getting any information for this thats why i am here to get your help
 thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<section id="feed"><!-- Header -->
<div>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
       <h2>come on say something</h2>
       <?php 
       include "database.php";
          $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
          $select_all = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all)) {
              $text = $row['articles'];
              $time = $row ['time_min'];

              ?>



<p><?php echo $text ?></p>
<p><span><?php echo $time ?></span></p>

 <?php }?>

 <?php function showDate($date) // $date Unix time
{
    $stf = 0;
    $cur_time = time();
    $diff = $cur_time - $date;

    $seconds = array('second', 'seconds', 'second');
    $minutes = array('minute', 'minutes', 'minutes');
    $hours = array('hour', 'hour', 'hours');
    $days = array('day', 'day', 'days');
    $weeks = array('week', 'weeks', 'week');
    $months = array('month', 'month', 'month');
    $years = array('year', 'yaer', 'years');
    $decades = array('dacade', 'decade', 'decades');

    $phrase = array($seconds, $minutes, $hours, $days, $weeks, $months, $years, $decades);
    $length = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);

    for ($i = sizeof($length) - 1; ($i >= 0) && (($no = $diff / $length[$i]) <= 1); $i--)
    {
        ;
    }
    if ($i < 0)
    {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $_time = $cur_time - ($diff % $length[$i]);
    $no = floor($no);
    $value = sprintf("%d %s ", $no, getPhrase($no, $phrase[$i]));

    if (($stf == 1) && ($i >= 1) && (($cur_time - $_time) > 0))
    {
        $value .= time_ago($_time);
    }

    return $value . ' ago';
}

function getPhrase($number, $titles)
{
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

    return $titles[($number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number % 10, 5)]];
} ?>

<?php $time = $row ['time_min']; ?>
<?php $time = strtotime($time); ?>
    <p><span><?php showDate($time) ?></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function showDate($date) // $date Unix time
{
    $stf = 0;
    $cur_time = time();
    $diff = $cur_time - $date;

    $seconds = array('second', 'seconds', 'second');
    $minutes = array('minute', 'minutes', 'minutes');
    $hours = array('hour', 'hour', 'hours');
    $days = array('day', 'day', 'days');
    $weeks = array('week', 'weeks', 'week');
    $months = array('month', 'month', 'month');
    $years = array('year', 'yaer', 'years');
    $decades = array('dacade', 'decade', 'decades');

    $phrase = array($seconds, $minutes, $hours, $days, $weeks, $months, $years, $decades);
    $length = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);

    for ($i = sizeof($length) - 1; ($i >= 0) && (($no = $diff / $length[$i]) <= 1); $i--)
    {
        ;
    }
    if ($i < 0)
    {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $_time = $cur_time - ($diff % $length[$i]);
    $no = floor($no);
    $value = sprintf("%d %s ", $no, getPhrase($no, $phrase[$i]));

    if (($stf == 1) && ($i >= 1) && (($cur_time - $_time) > 0))
    {
        $value .= time_ago($_time);
    }

    return $value . ' ago';
}

function getPhrase($number, $titles)
{
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

    return $titles[($number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number % 10, 5)]];
}
```

use it on site:

```
    <?php $time = $row ['time_min']; ?>
<?php $time = strtotime($time); ?>
    <p><span><?php showDate($time) ?></span></p>
```

Comment: how do i call it in my website?

Comment: because i want it display in my <p><span> here</span></p> like the way I am doing for my current one

Comment: <?php
$time = $row ['time_min'];

?>
<p><span><?php showDate($time) ?></span></p>

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getPhrase() in C:\wamp\www\project\feed.php on line 62

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare showDate() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\project\feed.php:34) in C:\wamp\www\project\feed.php on line 34

:(

Comment: it means that you already have such a function. Rename this one (showDate) into showDateInWords

Comment: please check my code and tell me where i am doing mistake. i am very glad you are helping, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to create a new answer, but...
Try to use some different style of programming

```
<?php
    require_once 'database.php';


    echo <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<section id="feed"><!-- Header -->
    <div>
        <h1>hello world</h1>

        <h2>come on say something</h2>
HTML;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $select_all = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all))
    {
        $text = $row['articles'];
        $time = $row ['time_min'];
        $time = showDate(strtotime($time));

        echo <<<HTML
<p>
    $text
</p>
<p><span> $time </span></p>
HTML;

    }

    function showDate($date) // $date Unix time
    {
        $stf = 0;
        $cur_time = time();
        $diff = $cur_time - $date;

        $seconds = array('second', 'seconds', 'second');
        $minutes = array('minute', 'minutes', 'minutes');
        $hours = array('hour', 'hour', 'hours');
        $days = array('day', 'day', 'days');
        $weeks = array('week', 'weeks', 'week');
        $months = array('month', 'month', 'month');
        $years = array('year', 'yaer', 'years');
        $decades = array('dacade', 'decade', 'decades');

        $phrase = array($seconds, $minutes, $hours, $days, $weeks, $months, $years, $decades);
        $length = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);

        for ($i = sizeof($length) - 1; ($i >= 0) && (($no = $diff / $length[$i]) <= 1); $i--)
        {
            ;
        }
        if ($i < 0)
        {
            $i = 0;
        }
        $_time = $cur_time - ($diff % $length[$i]);
        $no = floor($no);
        $value = sprintf("%d %s ", $no, getPhrase($no, $phrase[$i]));

        if (($stf == 1) && ($i >= 1) && (($cur_time - $_time) > 0))
        {
            $value .= time_ago($_time);
        }

        return $value . ' ago';
    }

    function getPhrase($number, $titles)
    {
        $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

        return $titles[($number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number % 10, 5)]];
    }
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\project\damo.php on line 37

Comment: for ($j = 0; $j < $select_all ->num_rows; ++$j)
   {
    $row = $select_all ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\project\damo.php on line 95